# MongoDB auth will not work

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, azure

I am running MongoDB on an Azure Ubuntu server and I cannot seem to activate authorization. As of now anyone can login to my db remotely. I have set an admin, set `auth=true` in `mongod.conf`, and specified the `--auth` option when starting my server; nothing seems to be working though. Are there any alternatives to the methods I listed?

Comment: Note: admin questions should be posted on DBA StackExchange :). Are you able to run queries when you connect to your remote instance or do they return an "unauthorized" error message? Have you followed the [tutorial to enable authorization](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) including creating the initial admin user? To limit remote access based on originating IP, you need to configure your firewall appropriately.

Comment: Hey, I was playing around with it for an hour and it just started working perfectly. I have no idea why it wasn't working before but everything is good now. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you didn't restart the MongoDB service? FYI, you can check the current command line options from a mongo shell using: `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`.